# Accessing IsVisible property of a XAML element's parent in code-behind

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

```cs
if (span.Text == "Specific String")
{
    var spanAncestor = span.Parent.Parent;
    spanAncestor.IsVisible = false; // Throws error. Read below.
}
```

The error I get is:

> Error CS1061  'Element' does not contain a definition for 'IsVisible'
> and no accessible extension method 'IsVisible' accepting a first
> argument of type 'Element' could be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)

The span has as a parent a `FormattedString`, which has as a parent a `Label`.

Is there a way to set `IsVisible` property for the ancestor element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Parent` is of type `Element`, which does not have an `IsVisible` property.  You need to cast it first

```
if (parent is VisibleElement)
{
  ((VisibleElement)parent).IsVisible = false;
}
```

Comment: Just tested. Spot on!

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Jason's answer, you could save the typecast, since you're already checking the type in the if-clause and do the following using [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/pattern-matching):

```cs
if (parent is VisibleElement visibleParent)
{
    visibleParent.IsVisible = false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I confirm it works too. Thanks for your input.